# Render Orchard Widgets without a page

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

We would like our Orchard CMS homepage to contain only widgets and no content items. We have **two approaches** that work:

**One**. Create a page, title it Home, and set it as the current homepage. Then use placement.info to hide its parts:

```
  <Match Path="/">
    <Match ContentType="Page">
      <Place Parts_Title="-"/>
      <Place Parts_Common_Metadata="-"/>
      <Place Parts_Common_Body="-"/>
    </Match>
  </Match>
```

This effectively gives us a homepage that displays only widgets. This approach, though, might confuse end users that add content to the site, because they will still see the "Welcome to Orchard!" page and wonder why its content isn't showing up on the site.

**Two**. Create a new content type  called WidgetContainer, that only has the Autoroute part. Then create an instance of it called Home, and set it as the homepage. This is a better approach.

Is there another way to map www.ourdomain.ca to a container that displays only widgets?

Answer (score 0):

Use this module: https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Contrib.Widgets

You can create a content type named `Widgets Page` for instance and add the widgets container part.